How do i make my jump more smooth instead of teleporting/snapping in gamemaker language
I tried multiple ways of making sure the jump is smooth. But every time I just get teleported instead of having a smooth jump :/
I tried using repeats, which did not change anything. I added yvel but that didn't help either.
Here is the script im using (for a platforrmer)
var xvel = 0;
var yvel = 0;


if (keyboard_check(vk_left)) {
    xvel = xvel - 5;
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_right)) {
    xvel = xvel + 5;    
}

if (!keyboard_check(vk_space)) {
    if (!place_meeting(x, y, obj_wall)) {
        yvel = yvel + 4;
    }
}else {
    if (place_meeting(x, y + 3, obj_wall)) {
        
        yvel = yvel - 5;
    }
}

x += xvel;
y += yvel;

if (yvel >= 0) {
    yvel = yvel - 1;
}else {
    yvel = yvel + 1;
}

if (xvel >= 0) {
    xvel = xvel - 1;
}else {
    xvel = xvel + 1;
}


I'm assuming this is all in the Step Event, So you should put this part below in the Create Event, and remove the var keywords, that makes the variable persistent for the object, and the Create Event will only be executed once at the start:
var xvel = 0;
var yvel = 0;

There are also other thoughts, like a gravity variable and collision checks (landing back on the ground) with varying speeds, but that gets too detailed. I'll recommend using a tutorial for this, as platforming collision is a tricky thing to get stuck into.
